# Make emacs gui use only terminal colours

Tags: emacs, colors

Since xterm supports only 16 colours, when you run emacs inside xterm, it  automatically maps the myriad colours defined by the various syntax colouring modes to one of the 16 terminal colours.  That's the behaviour I want to have on the emacs gui.

Is there a way to make the emacs gui believe that only the 16 terminal colours are available?

Also, can I disable mouse support in the emacs gui?  What I want is the gui to behave exactly like emacs inside xterm.

Thank you in advance!

(If you wonder why I want this: After nearly 15 years running emacs inside xterm, I'm sure that's what suits me best.
However, my new employer is forcing me to work on a Windows workstation and now I'm compelled to use the native emacs gui because I haven't managed to get ecb to run with cygwin's emacs.  I've already spent a lot of time trying to get the emacs gui to behave like emacs inside xterm, but I still have too many colours.)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but here are a couple of other options to consider: Using the Cygwin-native Emacs in an xterm, instead of using NTEmacs. Hosting a small (non-desktop) Linux VM on your Windows machine, and running Emacs inside of that (using Cygwin's X server for the local display; this was my own dev environment at one time, and it works nicely).

Comment: You might look at the definition of the `defined-colors` function as a place to start experimenting (I've no idea if that's *actually* relevant, but it seemed noteworthy).

Comment: emacs -nw works on Windows too, and genuinely does only support 16 colors (most xterms will support 256 or more these days).  However, like xterm, emacs -nw on Windows will also have mouse support these days.

Answer (score 2):

Your best chance may be to just use a color theme that just uses 16 colors for all faces.  The [Solarized](https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs) theme for example uses just about 16 colors even in a GUI Emacs.  It still makes use of bold and italic fonts, though, and occasionally (and very rarely) uses some lighter color variants to emphasize text, which might already be too much for you.

You could also compile your personal set of 16 colours, and customize the faces of your Emacs to use only these colors.

Comment: Also check out the Base16 and "tomorrow" themes: https://github.com/chriskempson/base16